# how to avoid below cell copy in to the above cell in extJs 3.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, datagrid, extjs3

I have `EditorGridPanel` data set. I want to disable some cell editable (check database that field record read-only is `YES`).

I did that calling `getSiteEditable`. I disable cell edit but when I click cell A (a read-only cell), after that I click `cancel` and double click on the Cell B, in that time cell B content copy in to the cell A.

Data store:

```
siteStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    idProperty: 'ROWI',
    root: 'data',
    autoLoad: true,
    mode: 'remote',
    url: WOERP.getURL("portals", "sm", "grid", "grid=portal_sm_configui_site_tab_grid&action=get"),
    keys: ['CONFIG_TYPE'],
    fields: [
        'ROWI',
        'CONFIG_VALUE',
        'CONFIG_DESC',
        'CONFIG_TYPE',
        'SHORT_DESC',
        'IS_READ_ONLY',
        'ROWDATE']
});

this.gridSiteData = Ext.ux.grid.woerp.getWoerpGrid(this.gridSiteData, siteStore);
siteRowEditor = Ext.getCmp('portal_sm_configui_site_tab_grid_roweditor');
siteRowEditor.on('beforeedit', this.getSiteEditable, this);
```

**setSiteEditable function**

```
getSiteEditable: function (roweditor, rowIndex) {
    if (!roweditor.initialized) {
        roweditor.initFields();
    }

    var fields = roweditor.items.items;

    var rec = this.gridSiteData.store.getAt(rowIndex);
    var isReadOnly = rec.data.IS_READ_ONLY;

    if (isReadOnly == 'YES') {
        Ext.each(fields, function (field, i) {
            if (field.name == 'CONFIG_VALUE') field.setDisabled(true);
        });
    } else Ext.each(fields, function (field, i) {
        if (field.name == 'CONFIG_VALUE') field.setDisabled(false);
    });
}
```

I can disable editable function by calling the above method, but when I click on data cell that copy below data cell content and show small red icon top of the click data cell.

Anyone know the reason of copying data into another cell?

**page load**
[image: page load view]
 **Double click on the cell A**
[image]
**After double click on the cell B(copy cell B content in to cell A)**
[image]

[image: after double click on the cell]

Comment: Do you still encounter this issue?